# arithmetic expression: expecting primary

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash, bashrc

I'm trying to add a function to the .bashrc file.

The function is supposed to change any Application window's opacity according to the command line argument.

```
opa(){
    sh -c 'xprop -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY $(printf 0x%x $((0xffffffff * $1 / 100)))'
}
```

I tried the above however it throws this error:

```
sh: 1: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "0xffffffff *  / 100"
usage:  xprop [-options ...] [[format [dformat]] atom] ...
```

How do I fix this? Also, is there any way to set a default value for the `$1` in case the user doesn't pass any command line argument?

Comment: `$1` won't be visible inside the `sh -c '...'` shell. But why are you even wrapping the `xprop` command inside a `sh -c`?

Comment: I'm not sure but I found this `sh -c 'xprop -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY $(printf 0x%x $((0xffffffff * 80 / 100)))'`
[here](https://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/11/12/make-app-window-transparent-ubuntu-18-04-18-10/).
Instead of using any variables, they're directly using the value as 80, I'm trying to make it as a variable and use a function for the big command

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense (to me at least) to start a subshell within a shell function - particularly not a `sh` shell inside `.bashrc`

Instead, you could just do

```
opa(){
    xprop -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY $(printf 0x%x $((0xffffffff * $1 / 100)))
}
```

If you want to supply a default value, you can do so using the `${parameter:-word}` or `${parameter-word}` syntax (depending on whether you want the default to take effect when `$1` is undefined or empty, or only when it is undefined)

- [BashGuide: Parameter Expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

i.e.

```
opa(){
    xprop -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY $(printf 0x%x $((0xffffffff * ${1:-60} / 100)))
}
```

If you *really* want to use a `sh -c '...'` subshell, you'd need to pass `$1` from the parent bash shell into the child `sh` shell

```
opa(){
    sh -c 'xprop -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY $(printf 0x%x $((0xffffffff * $1 / 100)))' sh "${1:-60}"
}
```